# C# WindowsForms не видит функцию .Bitmap, хотя все библиотеки подключил

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Добавление пользовательских библиотек...
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using DirectShowLib;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private VideoCapture capture = null;
        private DsDevice[] webCams = null;
        private int selectedCameraId = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webCams = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            for (int i = 0; i < webCams.Length; i++)
            {
                toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(webCams[i].Name);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripComboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedCameraId = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (webCams.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Нет доступных камер!");
                }
                else if (toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Необходимо выбрать камеру!");
                }
                else if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    capture = new VideoCapture(selectedCameraId);
                    capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed;
                    capture.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal).Bitmap;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Pause();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (capture != null)
                {
                    capture.Pause();
                    capture.Dispose();
                    capture = null;
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    selectedCameraId = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        //Сделать скриншот...
        private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                MakeScreenShotForm screenShotForm = new MakeScreenShotForm(m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal));
                screenShotForm.Show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка какая, и где?

Comment: private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mat m = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(m);
                pictureBox1.Image = m.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Flip(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FlipType.Horizontal).Bitmap;
            }

Comment: иии.... ошибка....? Что студия пишет?

Comment: "Image<Bgr, byte>" не содержит определения "Bitmap", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Bitmap", принимающий тип "Image<Bgr, byte>" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива "using" или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: У вас старый "гайд", библиотека изменилась, теперь для конвертации (как написано [в документации](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Converting_to_Bitmap)), нужен отдельный пакет [Emgu.CV.Bitmap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.Bitmap), как установите `.Bitmap` меняете на `.ToBitmap();`

Comment: Большое спасибо, час не мог найти нужную библиотеку
Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как отметить ваш ответ?